# Calling Stored procedure with 'IS IN' statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have following issue. I need to filter fetching data in stored procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE post_code IS IN ('pc1', 'pc2', 'pc3');
```

My question is: how to pass arguments pc1, pc2, pc3... into stored procedure?
As an array or as string? 
When I try pass as string I have problem with apostrophes.
Passing array in my opinion is not good because of performance...I will need to create for loop and create string which will be passed like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE post_code IS IN (post_codes);
```

How to do it right?

Comment: :First of all ,`IS IN` is not the correct syntax ,use `IN` only,I dnt see any function  call in your query above

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you think passing an array would lead to a performance issue.

This will work:

```
declare
    post_codes sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := new sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll ('pc1', 'pc2', 'pc3');
    lrec tab%rowtype;
begin
    select * into lrec
    where post_code in ( select * from table(post_codes));
end;
/
```

This is proof of concept only.  It will hurl TOO_MANY_ROWS exception if the query returns more than one row.  As you haven't provided any context for what you are trying to achieve I haven't bothered to invent anything exra.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, in my opinion is to use SQL to split up your string:

```
with id_generator
    as
    (
      SELECT regexp_substr(:txt, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) token
      FROM dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(:txt) - length(REPLACE(:txt, ',', '')) + 1
    )
    select u.id, u.username
    from users u, id_generator g
    where u.id = g.token;
```

This query looks a little scary, but you can take the top part and run it in isolation to see what it does:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(:txt, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) token
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(:txt) - length(REPLACE(:txt, ',', '')) + 1
```

This generates a row per item in your comma separated list, which you can then join to the other table to get your results.

More discussion on this problem on my blog - http://betteratoracle.com/posts/20-how-do-i-bind-a-variable-in-list

Comment: Easieness depends on context.  Is the starting point a string?  Or is the starting point a set of discrete values which have subsequently been concatenated together in an attempt to pass them to a query?